# avoid adding min-height by jquery mobile

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I built a APP using jQuery Mobile, I use phoneGap and My APP was built in a iframe as there is a frame for my platform(HP Anywhere). but jquery mobile will add a `min-height` css attribute on my `data-role="page"` DIV, acturlly one pix bigger than the max height of device, so it will cause some issues for me(T_T). I want to know: when will jquery mobile will add this CSS attribute on page div? and how to avoid that? thanks very much.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

jQuery Mobile sets page's `min-height` on two events, [`pageshow` (`pagecontainershow`)](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/blob/bdfe15d33c48b40473c32103f0e3acaa8b939834/js/navigation.js#L435-L448) and `throttledresize`. It calls [`resetActivePageHeight`](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/blob/2060bca3ce7ec8aa642eca5da59a8effd950d776/js/helpers.js#L186-L201) function for that.

To override it, do your changes on `pagecontainershow` and delay it a bit to ensure that `resetActivePageHeight` is done.

```
$(document).on( "pagecontainershow", function ( e, data ) {
   var activePage = data.toPage;

   setTimeout(function () {
      var currentHeight = activePage.css( "min-height" );
      activePage.css( "min-height", currentHeight - 1 ); /* subtract 1px or set your custom height */
   }, 50); /* set delay here */
});

$(window).on( "throttledresize", function ( e ) {
   var activePage = $.mobile.pageContainer.pagecontainer( "getActivePage" );

   setTimeout(function () {
      var currentHeight = activePage.css( "min-height" );
      activePage.css( "min-height", currentHeight - 1 );
   }, 50);
});
```

Comment: I added the code in my APP. but min-height is still there.

Comment: @jesse in that case instead of `activePage.css( "min-height", currentHeight - 1 );` remove style `activePage.removeAttr("style");` or set `min-height` to `auto`.

Comment: @omar: jqm 1.4.5: seems to me that just call again $.mobile.resetActivePageHeight() in pagecontainershow and throttledresize solved this.

Answer (score 1):

I have just hit this problem and found a simple solution.

It is caused by JQM calculating the page height, ending up with an answer which is larger than it should be, then inserting inline CSS to force the min-height of the 'page'. When I saw this, I searched the DOM from the data-role="page" DIV all the way up, looking for any element with a padding or margin setting that could affect the height calculation.

For me, the solution was to override the 'margin: 8px' set by the user agent on the BODY tag. Setting this to zero made JQM's height calculation work properly: the vertical scroll bars disappeared and so did the ability for the user to scroll vertically on pages shorter than the screen.

```
body {
    margin: 0;
}
```

Perhaps it's not the BODY tag for you, but you should check the hierarchy for anything suspicious that could trip up JQM.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure when it added it, but I assume the solution is to set a min-height with a value of 0, so it acts as it isn't there, while preventing CSS from producing it's own.

Comment: but I think jquery mobile will override `min-height`.

Comment: @jesse jQM will override it; inline `style` overrides classes.

Comment: @Omar yes, even add css in `style`, jquery mobile will override it as well

Answer (score 0):

To me, I remove that added min-height completely by adding the following css.

```
.ui-page.ui-page-active {
  min-height: auto !important;
}
```